# Android Firestore - Adicionar coleção

Tags: android, firebase, firestore

sou novato em Android, e tenho um arquivo JSON com dados de endereços de mercados da minha região e gostaria de importar para o firebase estes dados, mais precisamente para o Cloud Firestore. Alguém sabe como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Talvez as respostas deste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640981/how-to-import-csv-or-json-to-firebase-cloud-firestore) e este [artigo](https://hackernoon.com/filling-cloud-firestore-with-data-3f67d26bd66e) possam te ajudar. Utilizei eles uma vez.